# SKMaps bringToFrontAnnotation: method is working wrong

Tags: ios, skmaps

The problem I have is that when I call the method `bringToFrontAnnotation:` the annotation ignores its `minZoomLevel` property.

This is what I'm doing:

```
- (void)mapView:(SKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotation:(SKAnnotation *)annotation
{
    [mapView bringToFrontAnnotation:annotation];

    //...
}
```

Is there any way the annotation can attend again to its `minZoomLevel` property?

Answer (score 1):

The tap issue is actually a feature. The settings property of SKMapView has a property called annotationTapZoomLimit which by default is set to 12.

See: http://developer.skobbler.com/docs/ios/2.3.0/Classes/SKMapSettings.html#//api/name/annotationTapZoomLimit and SKMapView class reference: http://developer.skobbler.com/docs/ios/2.3.0/Classes/SKMapView.html